# Add Visual Damage to Sprite Shape Controller at Runtime Based on Collision Speeds

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I visually apply damage to a 2D car created using Sprite Shape Controller at runtime, based on the collision with another car, depending on their respective speed values?

I attempted to solve this issue using Sprite Shape Renderer but was unsuccessful. I tried converting Sprite Shape to a regular Sprite because deformation can be applied to Sprites. However, Sprite Shape does not update as a Sprite during runtime.